# Magento 2 | Override CustomerData-File

Tags: magento2, overrides

I want to override this file:

> /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/DefaultItem.php

I guess I have to do this by a module.

How do you override something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Create **di.xml** in Vendor/Module/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem" type="Vendor\Module\CustomerData\DefaultItem" />
</config>
```

2.Create file **DefaultItem.php** inside Vendor\Module\CustomerData

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\CustomerData;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

/**
 * Default item
 */
class DefaultItem extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem
{
         /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
         */
        protected $imageHelper;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data
         */
        protected $msrpHelper;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
         */
        protected $urlBuilder;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool
         */
        protected $configurationPool;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data
         */
        protected $checkoutHelper;

        /**
         * Escaper
         *
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
         */
        private $escaper;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
        \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $msrpHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool $configurationPool,
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper = null
    ) {
        $this->configurationPool = $configurationPool;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->msrpHelper = $msrpHelper;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->checkoutHelper = $checkoutHelper;
        $this->escaper = $escaper ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class);
    }

    protected function doGetItemData()
    {
        $imageHelper = $this->imageHelper->init($this->getProductForThumbnail(), 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail');
        $productName = $this->escaper->escapeHtml($this->item->getProduct()->getName());

        return [
            'options' => $this->getOptionList(),
            'qty' => $this->item->getQty() * 1,
            'item_id' => $this->item->getId(),
            'configure_url' => $this->getConfigureUrl(),
            'is_visible_in_site_visibility' => $this->item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
            'product_id' => $this->item->getProduct()->getId(),
            'product_name' => $productName,
            'product_sku' => $this->item->getProduct()->getSku(),
            'product_url' => $this->getProductUrl(),
            'product_has_url' => $this->hasProductUrl(),
            'product_price' => $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($this->item->getCalculationPrice()),
            'product_price_value' => $this->item->getCalculationPrice(),
           'product_image' => [
                'src' => $imageHelper->getUrl(),
                'alt' => $imageHelper->getLabel(),
                'width' => $imageHelper->getWidth(),
                'height' => $imageHelper->getHeight(),
            ],
            'canApplyMsrp' => $this->msrpHelper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($this->item->getProduct())
                && $this->msrpHelper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($this->item->getProduct()),
        ];
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: can i add new value to return, i am passing 'enable' =>'1' 
after canApplyMsrp is that allowed

e.g 
'canApplyMsrp' => $this->msrpHelper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($this->item->getProduct())
                && $this->msrpHelper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($this->item->getProduct()),
            'test' => '1',
and call this in html 
 ko if: test ==1
                    < h1 > test < / h1 >
                     /ko